# How to implement lazy loading and eager loading in EF generic repository?

Tags: c#

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class 
    {
        private readonly DBContext context; 
        public Repository(DBContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            context.Set<T>();
            return context.Set<T>();
        }
        public T Get(int id)
        {
            return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }
        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }
        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
        }
        public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            
            return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use the repository pattern with Entity Framework?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/25178)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this does not answer the question bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the eager loading requirement, I faced the same problem and resolved it using the [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-7.0) extension that accept a `String` as parameter.

I modified the signature of the `Get` method to allow user specify properties to load. This is the implementation (in this case asynchronous):

```
public interface IMyRepository  {
    ...
    Task<MyClass?> GetAsync(int id, params string[] includes);
    ...
}

public class MyRepository : IMyRepository {
...
    public async Task<MyClass?> GetAsync(int id, params string[] includes) {
        IQueryable<MyClass> qry = _dbContext.MySet;
        foreach (var include in includes) {
            qry = qry.Include(include);
        }
        // the following line is used to avoid complex joins 
        // when retrieving data 
        // you could implement some logic to decide when use it or not
        // qry = qry.AsSplitQuery(); 
        var result = await qry.SingleOrDefaultAsync(_ => _.Id == id);

        return result;
    }
...
}
```

Then use it in this way:

```
var item = await _repository.GetAsync(id, "SomeCollection", "SomeProperty");
```

I suggest to use `nameof` instead to *magic strings* to avoid errors at runtime:

```
var item = await _repository.GetAsync(id, nameof(MyClass.SomeCollection), nameof(MyClass.SomeProperty));
```

You could also use with sub-properties:

```
var item = await _repository.GetAsync(id, "SomeProperty.ChildProperty");
```

Regarding lazy loading, personally I prefer to avoid it (I used with NHibernate for many years) because there are a lot of side effects that require a very good knowledge of how it works.
Anyway you could see [Lazy Loading of Related Data (MS Learn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy?source=recommendations)